# How many people for concrete pour?

Tags: concrete, contractors

What size crew for monolithic slab pour: 10' x 20' x 5" thick, with 12" wide x 18" deep footer--about 5.5 to 6 cu yds? How many experienced versus inexperienced people are needed?  Contractor estimated 5 people for 6-8 hours. I'm going to assume he's not using a power screed or power float, but that still seems like a lot. There are a few stub ups and J-bolts may be wet set (haven't decided yet), but it's just a rectangle. What is a reasonable cost estimate for labor for the pour?

Edit for clarification: This will be poured from a truck. Truck can drive right up to a 20' side (anywhere along it) and has a 22' chute. No wheel barrowing needed. All rebar/structural support is in place. I'm just asking about from the time the truck arrives till the crew leaves. Truck driver doesn't do anything but drive the truck and adjust the mix & flow. Concrete company told me 1 person on chute, 1 person raking, 2 people screeding.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised it is only 5 people.

Comment: Last big job I had done - for 20'x24' garage floor (footers were already done) - had maybe 5-6 people on site for the initial pour, leveling, and screening.  That did not include the truck driver.  Then, half of them left and the remaining 2 or 3 waited for the concrete to set up a bit so they could do the final float and steel trowel finishing.

Comment: It depends.  You have the truck pouring in place all the way, a few people.  Start needing wheelbarrows the numbers go up.  Time is money, so a couple people spreading at each dump will shorten time.

Comment: Yep, if the truck can drive along each of the long sides, the number of guys is probably OK.  If the truck can only drive along one side, the dump chute reaching 20' would be questionable.

Comment: In my case, the truck was able to reach the entire pour site with its chutes, so no wheelbarreling was needed, that I can recall.

Comment: A contractor that's charging you per guy or w/e? Yeah, 6, for all day. - I'm doing it? Me and my guy, that's it. Only one of those 6 people know how to use a trowel anyway. Half a chance there's the one other guy they send to do just that, and he gets paid as much as four of them. So yeah, '6' guys. They're just putting crap down on paper so that the $5k bill makes sense.

Comment: If the driver isn't willing to kick the chute around once in a while then that company sucks. Nobody needs to be screeding until the raking is done. And when it's ready to float, everyone else has already gone home an hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

That's not unreasonable for that size slab. [This pour on YouTube uses upwards of 6 people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1XFWNT7pAM). Let's talk jobs for a second

1. Framing
2. Rebar setup (ideally tie the members together)
3. Pouring concrete
4. Spreading concrete
5. Troweling
6. Screeding (can cut this down some with a power screeder vs the common 2x4 scrape, but only saves one person)
7. Adjusting rebar (you could double up someone, but that's harder)
8. Final surface prep (grid lines, brushing, etc)

If they're doing this by hand or mixer (not via truck), add 1-3 people.